# How to remove an element from an array while iterating in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have an array from which an element should be removed. In order to do that, I have to iterate the array, find and remove the matching element. An array has `remove(int index)` method only as per the suggestions. How can I achieve this?

```
public class Observable {

    private Observer[] observers = [];

    public function addObserver(Observer observer) {
        self.observers.push(observer);
    }

    public function removeObserver(Observer observer) {
        var iterator = self.observers.iterator();
        foreach var obs in iterator {
            if obs === observer {
                // What should be added here?
                self.observers.remove()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, is the way I have obtained an iterator is correct?

Comment: IINM, though it can be used manually, it's meant to be used with foreach. For example, in the above case it'd be `foreach var obs in self.observers`

Comment: @Pubudu While iterating like that, can we remove items from the array without using `.remove(int index)` method?

Comment: No, that cannot be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this in Ballerina. I would suggest to use `lang.array:filter` method and create a new array excluding the members you wish to remove.

```
    int[] ar = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    int[] filtered = ar.filter(i => i != 2);
```